# BLE: Lower MTU value size(big difference) after MTU exchange

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt

I am new to the BLE development. I want to send some large amount of data over a BLE connection with maximum throughput.

I have a GATT server, which is running on Linux, and a client which is running as an app on Android. I have created a custom characteristic with the maximum allowed size(512 bytes). I am requesting it from the app with a read operation. Every time I receive a call for reading on the server side I change it's value until I am finished with all the data(I know this isn't the best way but that's not the problem for now).

As for the connection parameters using android's requestConnectionPriority(CONNECTION_PRIORITY_HIGH) i can see that they are trying to negotiate a connection interval of 7.5ms but for some reason, it changes to 15ms and it remains there. Maybe my phone doesn't support it but I don't think so.

The next thing and the main problem is the MTU. Using hcidump, I can see that they are starting to negotiate the MTU as I can see an MTU Request from the client with a value of 517(by default) and a server Response with the same value. But when I trigger the data exchange I can see(using Wireshark) that the packets are containing only 32 bytes of payload. I don't know if it's a restriction with my Bluetooth adapter.

Comment: So on protocol level this looks good. If you see the sever answer to 517 bytes, server and client have agreed on that. How do you send the data? Is the sending function restricting the size to 32 bytes?

Comment: @maze I think I missed this point.As a gatt server I am using some code that I have taken from here (https://github.com/Jumperr-labs/python-gatt-server) .This code is based on Bluez project and uses the Dbus-api.The main file is the gatt-server.py.In this file as you can see for example in line 370, you can create a class that's implementing a characteristic and with the use of ReadValue() you can return a value when a read operation is requested.In my case I am returning a string which contains my value(512 bytes).I don't know what's happening in lower levels but i don't think that's the case

Comment: My Bluetooth adapter supports the Bluetooth 4.0 version.Is it possible that this is the problem?

Comment: I am experiencing a similar issue - I have a nrf8240 based device that streams data to laptop using notifications. While MTU negotiation goes fine, I get only 32 bytes in my python script while device reports to send 100+ or so. I have traced it down to kernel drivers, but then I am lost there.

Comment: @miceuz I haven't found the solution but I think that this was a restriction by my BLE adapter. You should check your laptop's adapter in order to see which bluetooth version it supports. Another way is to use your (android or ios) phone instead of your laptop to see what are you receiving there. It is very simple to build an android app for that case. The documentation provided by android is quite good (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An MTU packet can consist of many radio packets and the 32byte radio packet payload is probably a restriction in your bluetooth adapter. No phone supports 7.5ms connection intervals at this point in time. You should also enable Data Length Extention if your phone and device supports it. This will allow you to transmit multiple MTUs throughout the connection event.

Comment: Do you know how can I achieve this.Can I initiate it from Android because i don't think i can from the Peripheral's side

Comment: A peripheral can initiate a Link Layer Length Request, but the central (Android) must support this feature. I can also recommend switching to the 2mbps PHY, but only the newest phones on the market supports it. 

I'm afraid I do not know the Android BLE API, but you should find it under the GAP or LL API references.