# BLE: adapter sending data using HCI ACL protocol instead of LE LL

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, gatt

I have created an Android app which acts as the central and I have found an implementation of a gatt-server (github.com/Jumperr-labs/python-gatt-server) which is part of bluez.When I am asking with a read request the value of a characteristic from the server, the resulting packets are sent using the HCI ACL protocol which is not right as I know.I have set my adapter to LE only mode using btmgmt but i see the same results.Am I missing something?

Here is the current adapter settings taken from the command 'btmgmt info'
    "current settings: powered connectable le advertising secure-conn"

Here is what Wireshark shows
[Wireshark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmArl.png)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly where you see those ACL packets, but the BLE data packets are indeed sent as ACL data packets over HCI.

If you see that the connection uses Bluetooth Classic, you can from the Android side set the transport parameter to TRANSPORT_LE in the connectGatt call to force BLE.

Comment: I have already set this in Android or else I couldn't connect to the server but in some other photos around the net i have seen that wireshark says in the sending packages that LE LL protocol is used.If you can check in my profile this comes from another question that I have asked

Comment: Are you noticing any particular problem or is your question about understanding how it works? Can you send a screenshot of your log?

Comment: I have added in the original post what wireshark shows.I am trying to understand if this is normal.The main question is in this post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50255842/ble-lower-mtu-value-sizebig-difference-after-mtu-exchange) but i believed that this problem was an adapter restriction as someone mentioned, until i saw this in Wireshark which i thought it was the real problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have found somewhere that wireshark as well as hcidump does the analyzing on HCI level without being able to see the lower layers.And as soon as in HCI BLE packets are sent as ACL data it's fine!To see the lower layers you must buy a BLE sniffer USB dongle.